# iOS: Storing user registration details

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rubymotion

I an building my first iOS application and I need to store the user registration details of the user using the application. The details include his mobile number and a unique id( uuid ) which I use to contact with the backend. It would be great if I could get a suggestion on where to store this user details.

Should I be storing this in the NSUserDefaults or should I be using Keychains to store this data or even may be a using a user model in the database ( I would need a database in any case to store a few other details ). Just to add on, I also would like to perform a few validations like if the mobile number is of proper format and so on before I could actually save it. Also can any one please suggest on the security aspects of different storage mechanisms possible here?

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most secure way would be to use `keychain` services as the data is encrypted but in your scenario it seems a bit over kill. I would recommend either just using `NSUserDefaults` or an `sqlite database` I wouldn't really recommend storing in a `plist` as this can be accessed really easily.

But this all depends on the data you are getting, if it was just `uuid` and mobile number then `NSUserDefaults` would do probably, whereas if you were getting usernames and passwords and other personal data I would looking a mix of `keychain` and `sqlite database`.

Also you could use coredata file to store user data but seems a bit over kill as well for for such little data.

Just a little note you are actually not allowed to get the iPhones mobile phone number programmatically, getting this would use **Private APIs** that Apple would reject your app for using.

> 2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

So you would have to ask he user for this.

Comment: I guess you mean "Just a little not you are actually *not* allowed"

Answer (score 0):

Database selection is totally depend on the architecture and security, if you just need to store the few information like login details and some field then Keychain for login details and plist for data is best option, but if your application also working with services and fetching and saving lots of data and continuously updating it then a serious database structure required. In that scenario core data and sqlite both are good option depends on your preference

Comment: Yeah, I do have to play around with some load of data where I need to store informations like contacts of a particular user etc. But my question is more specific to storing details of the user who is using the app. For eg, something like uuid has to be stored securely. Will it be good to have a database table named User with just one row in it ?

Comment: Yes, its possible and Apple also do things like that :) and if you are more concern about the security then you can encrypt data or use keychain

Answer (score 0):

Following ways you can save details.

1. In NSUserDefaults
2. In coredata file.
3. In sqlite database
4. Plist file.(Not recommended)
5. You can save data at server site using webservice.

Any one of these you can use according to your requirement and data.
Cheers :)

Comment: Please whatever you do don't store it in a `plist` file. Good that you have suggested it but probably the worst option.

Answer (score 0):

If you store information on the UserDefaults, a jailbroken device can see the information you have stored, it is a plist after all. If you are going to keep sensitive data on your device, user defaults itself is not a good option. Possible alternatives:

1. Use keychain: Keychain is a tool to keep usernames & passwords securely on a device; so you may need to find a way to convert all the info you have mentioned ( a dict, I presume? ) into NSData and put into/get from the keychain but it's been explained on other threads. Additionally, keep in mind that when the app is deleted, keychain data will persist on the device.
2. UserDefaults & encrpytion: If you can encrypt the data yourself, than using UserDefaults might be a better option. Its more straightforward than keychain and it will be deleted if you delete the app from the device (which may be the thing you want, or not. It depends)

Comment: UserDefaults & encryption is kinda useless, because you have to save the secret that was used to encrypt the data somewhere. And if that somewhere is not the keychain an attacker can access the secret without any problems.

Comment: But how? Can they decompile the source code that easily from the binary? Or doesn't it depend on the encryption method you are using?

Comment: You will encounter the same dilemma for all encryption methods. Your app needs access to the secret to encrypt and decrypt the data. And if your app can get the secret an attacker who has access to your app can get the secret as well. Decompiling, swizzling methods and so one, there are various ways to get access to the secret that is stored in an app. Sure, there are ways to prevent that by obfuscating code, not using Objective-C and so on. But that won't stop a serious attacker. You just shift the problem from using the keychain to hiding the secret.

Comment: I am aware that this is irrelevant in this specific case because the data is pretty much worthless, nobody will extract the secret from the app. It's just general advice. The keychain API sucks big time, but it's the best thing you have if you want to save encrypted data locally. If you need to save more data you can of course encrypt it yourself, but please store the secret in the keychain.